# Adding windows dual boot to second disk broke linux

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows, windows-10

Ive had my linux pc for some time now and just today, i decided to put windows as dual boot on it.

I have two disks: /dev/sda was my 1TB additional data drive /dev/sdb has my operating system on it

I firstly deleted all files from /dev/sdb, as i wabted to put windows on that. I had /dev/sda mounted under /mnt/data/, so i tried doing sudo umount /mnt/data/, i dont know if that did anything.

So I continued, used an usb stick to install windows on the 1TB disk and everything worked fine. Windows 10 Pro installed onto the 1TB disk after I deleted the partitions from it using the windows installation assistant thing, and i can now use windows.

Later, I tried booting up Linux. I got as far as for Grub and then the preboot launcher to start, which allowed me to select the linux kernel (I think im using 5).

soon after that however did I run into the problem: During boot itwould run into an error with the disks and file system and boot into emergency mode. An image of the [error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLneS.jpg) of error.

Now I dont know what to do, emergency mode runs just fine, I just cant figure out how to get linux to forget the disk which was formerly /dev/sda. I dont understand the stuff with kernel patches one finds when searching online and I dont really know what to do.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You deleted everything from `/dev/sdb`, so you deleted your Linux. How do you then expect Linux to boot without reinstalling it again? Also, you write, that you wanted to put Windows on `/dev/sdb` (so, instead of Linux that was there), but you finally placed Windows on `/dev/sda`. Can you explain those incosistencies?

Comment: You will need to edit the `/etc/fstab` file. Comment out the line that tries to mount `/mnt/data`. From there you should be able to reboot the machine and load Linux properly 

Comment: Normally grub bootloader installs to first drive, often sda. Is system UEFI or BIOS. are installs all UEFI or all BIOS?  Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in correct UEFI or BIOS boot mode as both installs.